# Problem concerning the real Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

The real quadratic  Nullstellensatz says:

Let $p(x), q(x)\in \mathbb R[x_1,...,x_n]$ be quadratic polynomials such that 
$$(*) \  \{x\in \mathbb R^n: p(x)=0\}=\{x\in \mathbb R^n: q(x)=0\}$$
and $p(x)$ has at least one zero $x_0$ such that $grad \ p(x_0) \neq 0$. 
Then there is a $\alpha \in \mathbb R^*$ such that $p=\alpha q$.

Is the same true if the condition (*) is replaced by the following one:
$$
(*) \  \{x\in \mathbb R^n: p(x)=0\} \subset \{x\in \mathbb R^n: q(x)=0\} ?
$$

Answer (score 0):

According to my answer [elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/a/290170/85592) to a related question, if $\{p=0\}$ is contained in $\{q=0\}$ then $p$ divides $q$ in $\mathbf R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. (If the condition of irreduciblity of $p$ [there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/290170/85592) is not fulfilled, $p$ is simply the product of two linear polynomials that do not have a common zero in $\mathbf R^n$. That case is easy to handle.) Since $p$ and $q$ are both of degree $2$, there is $\beta\in\mathbf R$ such that $q=\beta p$. Since $q$ is not identically zero on $\mathbf R^n$, the real number $\beta$ is nonzero. Let $\alpha=\beta^{-1}$. Then $p=\alpha q$.